# How to Implement User input in a macOS Package Installer Script Using Bash and osascript?

Tags: bash, macos, authentication, installation, osascript

I'm currently working on a macOS package installer script, and I need to incorporate a user input step during installation. The goal is to create a form that prompts the user for input and performs authentication based on the entered credentials.

I've considered using `osascript` to display a dialog box for user input, but I'm unsure about the best approach to handle authentication within the script.

Can someone please provide guidance on how to properly create a user input form during a macOS package installation script and implement authentication based on the entered credentials? Any insights, best practices, or code examples would be greatly appreciated.